# IVY not retrieving all libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ivy, ivyde

I have two Eclipse instances using same SVN repository (updated to HEAD). Both are using same IVY-version and same IVY-configuration (to extent what I can find). IVY-settings and ivy.xml are identical as saved in SVN repository.

Yet I'm facing an issue where the other instance is not retrieving all the libraries that the other one is retrieving - thus resulting in runtime errors. IVY-report in other is just missing those dependencies...

The libs that are not loaded are all related to main-dependency 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws' which have transitive dependency to 'cxf-rt-frontend-simple' which eventually have these as transitive dependencies:

> geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
> jakarta.jws-api-2.1.0.jar jakarta.xml.soap-api-1.4.2.jar
> jakarta.xml.ws-api-2.3.3.jar saaj-impl-1.5.3.jar stax-ex-1.8.3.jar
> xercesImpl-2.12.2.jar

The Eclipse missing some libraries is 2019-06 (4.12.0) and the other is 2023-03 (4.27.0) - if that matters in any way.

IVY-version is the same in both Eclipse instances, 2.5.1. IvyDE seems to be same in both but I'm not entirely sure as the old Eclipse's marketplace doesn't show any supported IvyDE plugins. Though the version for both shows the same, 2.2.0.final-201311091524-RELEASE.

Of course now I have the option to use the working one, but I would really like to know what is the issue if it would some day occur in the other Eclipse instance as well.
Any suggestions on what to check?